# Are Outlook rules recursive?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

If I create a rule to move all mail from user@test.com into my "User" folder, will it move all of the mail from user@test.com that's in my Inbox to the same folder as well?  Or, will it just move new mail into that folder?

Comment: `retroactive` may be the word you're looking for

Comment: recursion  (rɪˈkɜːʃən)
— n
1.  the act or process of returning or running back

Comment: You really don't mean "recursive".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will just move new e-mails.
There is an option when you set the rule up to run on messages already in the inbox

Comment: Thanks - do I have this option in Outlook 2003 and Outlook 2010?

Comment: You certainly do in Outlook 2003, I haven't used Outlook 2010 yet so can't be sure but it has been a consistent through every edition of Outlook I have used so I imagine so yes.